# How could I align my label text to the top left side of the input box?

Tags: html, css

Currently my web page looks like this

[image]

And I am wanting it to look like this

[image]

I have thought about putting "Email Address" and "ZIP" inside of their own span tag, but I am not sure the best way to approach it.

My code looks like this:

```
.emailBox {
  padding-left: 13px;
  font-family: Rubik; 
  z-index: 1;
  top: 300px;
  width: 317px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #f5f6f7;
  border: none;
}
.zipBox {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 13px;
  font-family: Rubik; 
  z-index: 1;
  top: 300px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #f5f6f7;
  border: none;
}

<div>
    <form action="https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/1681335/pq0txq/" method="POST">
        <label>Email Address <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@shinesolar.com" class="emailBox">
        </label>
        <label>ZIP <br>
            <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="72712" class="zipBox">
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your current CSS in the snippet.

Comment: Try and make sure your label has a text align of left
or at least show your css or include your it in the snippet

Comment: `label {text-align:left;}`

Comment: You could make a div around each inputs and then align the text to the left side as you want.